# Pause a thread while timeout

Tags: c++, qt, udp, nonblocking, qthread

I have a thread for a connection UDP.

I want to pause my thread while timeout (or while there isn't new frames in my QStack which stores UDP frames).

```
run(){

    forever{
         QTimer *timer_nb = new QTimer();
         timer_nb->start(500);

         // --- Wait for timeout or new frames in my QStack
         //then ....
    }
}
```

I found a function select(), but I don't really understand how it works ...
Is there an alternative with Qt ?

(Sorry for my english)

Comment: before you do any work with sockets, you need to read the documentation. You will need to understand select() perfectly.

Comment: plus, select() is a Windows function, right ? is there an alternative for Linux then ?

Comment: select() is part of the Berkeley sockets interface and therefore portable. The equivalent on Linux is... select()

Comment: With Qt’s socket classes, one wouldn’t use select directly though, but listen to a signal like readyRead(). @Bastien Nicolau: I’d suggest to handle both timeout and “new frames” in slots and use the thread’s event loop instead of  the forever loop.

Comment: You need event loop to have fully functional `QTimer`. classic problem of understanding how to use threads in qt  http://blog.qt.io/blog/2010/06/17/youre-doing-it-wrong/ . IMO it is best to do it without threads.

Answer (score 1):

The Qt mindset is most of the time to work with events, the Qt event loop will do the wait/pause for you. Though `select` (`pselect` on linux) does exactly what you want... it is not the Qt way.

A Qt way of doing it could be to connect to both signals of *a new frame received* and *a timeout occured*. If your objects are created in your UDP thread, their slots will be executed in the same thread ([doc about this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#thread-affinity)).

You can initialize in the `run` function and create+connect the signals to some custom slot(s), then instead of calling `forever` you just call `exec()` ([doc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#exec)). The `run` function will not return and therefore not terminate your thread, but will be waiting for events until you terminate the thread yourself by calling `exit()`. You can call it yourself when you have received what you want, or from the main thread to just stop processing the frames at some point.

Then you need a custom slot which process new frames and reset the QTimer to restart the timeout from 0. And eventually another custom slot to handle the timeout, or the same slot depending on what you have to do when it happens.

Now you can see your code is not blocking, so you could probably do all of this directly in the main thread, except if the data processing is long.